# How to run Karma tests from docker container?

Tags: javascript, docker, karma-runner

I've recently moved my node.js app into a docker image and I'd like to run my tests inside the image. My mocha/node tests work fine but the Karma tests involve starting Chrome to run the tests and Chrome isn't installed in the container.

How do I go about addressing this?

- Install Chrome in the Container? Seems less than ideal as I don't want to ship Chrome to my production servers inside the container.
- Somehow allow it to connect to Chrome on the host?
- Create a new image that inherits from my app image and adds Chrome and other things?

Googling 'docker & karma' reveals docker images out there but I can't find instructions on how to think about the problem and the best approach.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles/blob/master/chrome/stable/Dockerfile about Chrome

Comment: Thanks I've read the blog post behind that before but it doesn't clarify for me how to proceed in this case.

Comment: if you go with "Create a new image that inherits from my app image and adds Chrome and other things?", you will need supervisor https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/using_supervisord/ or such (s6, runit, daemon tools...) to manager your processes

Answer (score 3):

I've found this docker image to be an excellent starting point for running karma tests quickly inside a docker container on Concourse CI:

https://hub.docker.com/r/markadams/chromium-xvfb-js/

It contains node 6.x (latest) + npm and a headless chromium instance using X virtual framebuffer. Working great for me!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what are you doing? Do you thing it is possible use docker-compose and run this in a separate container? or my tests must run in the container with this image?

Comment: @amp the tests must run inside this container. The whole point of this container is that it contains a chromium install that is able to execute karma tests. You can start the container however you like, then e.g. use `docker exec`, or alternatively use the container image as the base for your own Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [protractor-runner](https://github.com/hortonworks/docker-e2e-protractor) project, and Karma is similar to running Protractor, and so you might be able to learn how to do it from that example.    But, I prefer the suggestion to use `chromium-xvfb-js` image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (tested in Alpine Linux):

**Option 1**

1. Ensure that the `9876` port is accessible from the *host*.
2. Install **chromium**:

   ```
    apk add chromium # NOT google-chrome-stable
   ```
3. Create a wrapper script that starts `chromium-browser` in **headless** mode:

   ```
    vi /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
   ```

   Add the following lines:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh

    chromium-browser \
    --no-sandbox \
    --headless \
    --disable-gpu \
    --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
    "$@"
   ```
4. Make it executable:

   ```
    chmod +x /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
   ```
5. Run the tests in *headless* mode:

   ```
    ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless
   ```

---

**Option 2**

You can also run the browser in a **virtual** X Server called **Xvfb**:

5. Remove the `--headless` option in the `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` script.
6. Start the server and export the `DISPLAY` vairable:

   ```
    Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
    export DISPLAY=:1
   ```
7. Run the tests:

   ```
    ng test
   ```

Answer (score -4):

Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instead of Chrome. Karma has [PhantomJS launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher).

PhantomJS based on Blink.

Install PhantomJS:

```
npm karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

Add to Karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers : ['PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

**EDIT**

Here is part od `Dockerfile`

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 0.12.7
ENV NPM_VERSION 3.5.1
ENV PHANTOM_JS phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64

# App and test
RUN set -x \
    && buildDeps='curl git bzip2 file libfreetype6 libfontconfig1 python-pip python-dev libpq-dev libmemcached-dev libzmq-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev zlib1g-dev libtiff5-dev make g++ psmisc' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -SLO "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2" \
    && tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 \
    && mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share \
    && ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --verify SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz\$" SHASUMS256.txt.asc | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xzf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && npm install -g npm@"$NPM_VERSION" grunt-cli \
    && npm install \
    && npm cache clear \
    && ./node_modules/.bin/bower install --allow-root \
    && npm test \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/include/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

In this case Docker made one layer. In this layer

1. install libs and tools (debian jessie)
2. install PhantomJS
3. install NodeJS
4. run tests
5. remove libs and tools
6. remove NodeJS
7. remove PhantomJS

Tests are running and You don't have PhantomJS in production container.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I might try this approach though it is possible to launch Chrome from docker so I'm more curious about finding the best way forward. Mostly, it is it possible to keep the docker container fairly minimal or do I have to add all the testing stuff to it as well? I already have npm modules for test so maybe it isn't unreasonable to apt-get install chrome and selenium as well but it feels less than ideal. Perhaps my test script can add the dependencies as part of the test? But that seems a bit heavy as well.

Comment: I don't think it's good idea to use Chrome inside Docker. PhantomJS based on Chrome WebKit and it's very good alternative to run test. Chrome needs X11 to run. PhantomJS not. To runSelenium use GhostDriver.

Comment: I take your point. My question at this point is whether it is a good idea or standard practice to ship PhantomJS to production because I need it in my image for testing or whether there is a way to run the tests without adding all the testing infrastructure to the production image.

Comment: Chrome no longer uses Webkit: https://codereview.chromium.org/13529015/

Comment: PhantomJS is currently deprecated. [Github issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344). It is advised to run ChromeHeadless or FirefoxHeadless. [ChromeHeadless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai)