# How to run unit tests inside Docker container

Tags: angular, docker, karma-jasmine

I have created a docker container which runs my angular project and now I'm trying to run my unit tests inside the container unsuccessfully. I need a headless browser to run my tests and PhantomJS is too buggy for my taste, also gives different results with Chrome, when running tests.

Here, I provide my Dockerfile:

```
# download (or use if it's in cache) the latest official image from node
FROM node:latest

# create directory in the container and set all privileges
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && chmod 777 /usr/src/app

# make the directory available for following commands
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all local's frontend content to the WORKDIR
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I tried using Headless Chrome, but still it needs some more configuration that I don't know how to do it. Anyone having any thoughts?

Comment: Months ago I had problems with the headless browser and some of the tests were failing because it can't scroll the browser to the element I was trying to see if they exist. If you have some tests that are failing, keep that in mind.

Anyway why do you run ng serve instead of ng test?

Comment: because I will run the 'test' command in a later moment

Comment: Are you using the Selenium webdriver for NodeJS or you are using protactor?

Comment: I am running the tests using preconfigured karma, as I use Angular CLI. I don't really know which of the two are being used. how can I check it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Karma tests from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286210/how-to-run-karma-tests-from-docker-container)

Comment: hi @Nishant. it's been 5 years since I posted the question and below you can see that I actually did the same thing that you suggested in that question ;)

Comment: True, @PanosVakalopoulos :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a lot of investigation, I found a way to do this:

I installed Chrome inside my frontend Dockerfile:

```
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y google-chrome-stable
```

and I used headless Chrome for my tests with the proper configuration inside karma.config:

```
browsers: ['Chrome_without_sandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
  Chrome_without_sandbox: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox'] // with sandbox it fails under Docker
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium, I would suggest that you create a different container where the selenium tests will be executed, we'll call this `selenium-container`. Since you are using Node, there is an existing [selenium webdriver for node](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver) that you can write your unit tests in.

Alongside that container, you can use [the chrome standalone server](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) as the headless browser so that you can execute your unit tests from selenium-container, we'll call this `chrome-container`.

When writing your unit tests, you can start your tests by connecting to the headless browser server with something like this:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
```

This is just to get you started, the API is well documented and easy to use in order to write your tests.

It's good to isolate the unit tests from your Angular project so that they don't interfere with one another in any way. Starting the test can be done in just one command using [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Your `docker-compose.yml` may look something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  angular-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  selenium_container: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.selenium.test
    depends_on:
      - chrome-container
      - angular-app
  chrome-container:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0-einsteinium
```

Comment: thanks. I'm gonna give it a try, since I'm not proficient yet with Docker and I'm gonna give you update about that the following days.

Comment: @PanosVakalopoulos Then this is a great way to learn the core concepts of Docker such as running multiple containers, linking them together, and docker-compose, good luck!

Comment: why should I investigate over selenium, since I'm working now, only for unit testing? Isn't selenium webdriver needed only for e2e tests?