# No captured browser

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have been searching through various responses on this issue and still havent found a resolution. Has anyone been able to fix the karma warning? This is an angular project.

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
12 12 2022 02:51:03.216:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
12 12 2022 02:51:03.225:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
12 12 2022 02:51:03.225:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
12 12 2022 02:51:03.229:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
12 12 2022 02:51:03.752:INFO [Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket VbweAHLyodUBm4G5AAAB with id 55148481
Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 17 of 17 SUCCESS (0.123 secs / 0.085 secs)
TOTAL: 17 SUCCESS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Karma not running unit tests due to "No captured browser" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513650/karma-not-running-unit-tests-due-to-no-captured-browser-message)

Comment: This does not solve this issue.